How is it possible to allow RDP with multiple users simultaneously on Windows Server 2019 without the RDProle?
My friend works in a company from home remotely via RDP.
They have 5 employees who are simultaneously connected to Windows Server 2019.
I checked and saw that no RDP role was installed on that server.
They just created 5 users with admin privileges ( administrators group ).
I know only 2 people can connect at the same time, so how did they do it?
How did they allow 5 people to connect at the same time?
And they didn't install any hacks or anything like RDP Wrapper.
RDP Wrapper doesn't even work at this version.

Should not be possible. Either they have something installed that handles RDP, eg Terminal Services role, a third-party RDP server, a hack like RDP Wrapper, or they just have multiple Windows Server 2019 environments and people actually connect to different servers. In any case, it is impossible for us to answer how they did it, which makes this question off-topic for SuperUser. If you really want to know, ask their IT.

@LPChip i dont know who are they

Sorry, but we can't help you. This is a Question and Answers site, where you post a question, we give an answer, you can test that the answer works, and mark it as solved. In this case that is not possible. Also it is speculation on what they may or may not have done, aka opinions, which is also considered Off-topic for this site. Feel free to visit the help center to find out what kind of questions you should be asking.
